# Finding maximal cliques in a graph represented as a collection of complete biparti graphs

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

I have a graph whose edges can be very efficiently represented as a set of complete biparti graphs (that may share nodes). Is there a name for such a representation?

And secondly. I want to enumerate the maximal cliques in this graph. Intuitively the more compact representation of the graph should improve performance. But I can't find anything in the literature, so any insights or references are welcome.

Comment: I think the previous statement was more mathematically sound. Instead of replacing it, you can just add the above statement.

Comment: I don't understand what it means for an edge to be " represented as a set of complete bipartite graphs (that may share nodes)".  Can you give a mathematical definition?

Comment: @D.W.
The whole graph is represented as such. Apologies for the confusion.

It's like in "On covering graphs by complete bipartite subgraphs, by S. Jukna and A.S. Kulikov, 2009"

Quote: "The biclique covering number () of a graph  is the smallest number of bicliques (complete bipartite subgraphs) of  such that every edge of  belongs to at least one of these bicliques."

And for some graphs () is quite small. As in my case.